# What technology for large scale scraping/parsing?

Tags: parsing, screen-scraping, large-data-volumes

We're designing a large scale web scraping/parsing project. Basically, the script needs to go through a list of web pages, extract the contents of a particular tag, and store it in a database. 
What language would you recommend for doing this on a large scale(tens of millions of pages?).
.

We're using MongoDB for the database, so anything with solid MongoDB drivers is a plus.

So far, we have been using(don't laugh) PHP, curl, and [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but I don't think that's scalable to millions of pages, especially as PHP doesn't have proper multithreading.

We need something that is easy to develop in, can run on a Linux server, has a robust HTML/DOM parser to easily extract that tag, and can easily download millions of webpages in a reasonable amount of time.
We're not really looking for a web crawler, because we don't need to follow links and index all content, we just need to extract one tag from each page on a list.

Answer (score 7):

If you're really talking about *large* scale, then you'll probably want something that lets you scale horizontally, e.g., a Map-Reduce framework like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). You can write Hadoop jobs in a number of languages, so you're not tied to Java. Here's an article on [writing Hadoop jobs in Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Writing_An_Hadoop_MapReduce_Program_In_Python), for instance. BTW, this is probably the language I'd use, thanks to libs like [`httplib2`](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) for making the requests and [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) for parsing the results.

If a Map-Reduce framework is overkill, you could keep it in Python and use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

UPDATE: 
If you don't want a MapReduce framework, and you prefer a different language, check out the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) in Java. I would definitely use the Apache Commons HTTP client stuff, though. The stuff in the JDK proper is way less programmer-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use tools used for testing web applications (WatiN or Selenium).

You can then compose your workflow separated from the data using a tool I've written.

https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests

You shouldn't have to do any manual parsing when using WatiN or Selenium.  You'll instead write an css querySelector.

Using TopShelf and NServiceBus you can scale the # of workers horizontally.

FYI: With mono these tools i mention can run on Linux. (although miles may vary)

If JavaScript doesn't need to be evaluated to load data dynamically:
Anything requiring the document to be loaded in memory is going waste time.  If you know where your tag is, all you need is a sax parser.

Comment: By the way NServiceBus provides (distribution, persistence, security, transactions, and reliability to queue work) - sample: https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NWebHooks

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar using Java with the HttpClient commons library. Although I avoid the DOM parser because I'm looking for a specific tag which can be found easily from a regex.

The slowest part of the operation is making the http requests.

Answer (score 0):

what about c++? there are many large scale libraries can help you.

[boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) can help you do the network.

[TinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/) can parse XML files.

I have no idea about database, but almost all database have interfaces for c++, it is not a  problem.